# Python elasticsearch dsl search multi fields and order result

Tags: python, pyelasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

How can i search in elasticsearch dsl python module on multi fields, example on `title` and `body` field and order it by `created_at` field DESC.

I have this example that search only on `title` field:

```
q = request.GET.get('q', None)
s = Search(using=elastic_client, index='post').query('match', title=q)
response = s.execute()
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found solution:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import MultiMatch

q = request.GET.get('q', None)
query = MultiMatch(query=q, fields=['title', 'body'], fuzziness='AUTO')
s = Search(using=elastic_client, index='post').query(query)
response = s.execute()
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also [MultiSearch](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#multisearch) class now. So you it's possible:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import MultiSearch, Search

ms = MultiSearch(index='post')

ms = ms.add(Search().filter('term', tags='title'))
ms = ms.add(Search().filter('term', tags='body'))

responses = ms.execute()
```

and then you can and group it, and order, and so on. But result is a collection of responses by every filter.